# Why do multiple setTimeouts only execute once on IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, settimeout

I've checked other entries about this but none of them seem to be my problem.  The HTML page below runs perfectly well on Chrome.  There are three lines output.

On IE9, however, only the first line is output.  Any ideas on why this might be?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var process = (function () {

            var count = 0;    

            function _execute() {
                count++;
                document.write("Executed " + count + " time(s).<br\>");
            }

            return {
                add: function () {

                    setTimeout(_execute, 50);
                }
            };
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    process.add();
    process.add();
    process.add();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output Chrome:

```
Executed 1 time(s).
Executed 2 time(s).
Executed 3 time(s).
```

Output IE9:

```
Executed 1 time(s).
```

Comment: Hunch: IE9 is keying the timers by a reference to the function object.  Try wrapping each call in an anonymous function: `setTimeout(function() {_execute()}, 50)`

Comment: @Nevir interesting guess; I suppose it's possible. Seems like a serious bug however. *edit* - oh wait; it's a `document.write()` thing I bet.

Comment: Try replacing `document.write()` with `console.log()`.  Calling `document.write()` after the document is closed (which can definitely happen here) will blow away the whole thing.

Comment: You are a brilliant man (or woman) Pointy.  The problem was the document.write().  I replaced it with a div on the page and did the innerHTML thing and it's peachy now.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use document.write after the page loads! View the page source. You will see it replaces the entire document.

Use appendChild or innerHTML to add new content to the page. If you are debugging, use the console.

```
    var process = (function () {

        var count = 0,
            outElem = document.getElementById("out");

        function _execute() {
            count++;
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = "Executed " + count + " time(s)";
            outElem.appendChild(li);
        }

        return {
            add: function () {

                setTimeout(_execute, 50);
            }
        };
    })();
```

[running Example with appendChild](http://jsfiddle.net/d7CRN/)

Comment: The document.write was just to test what I was doing, it wasn't a production thing.  Since it was something asynch I was testing -- that caused issues. Problem was solved when another method was used to produce the output.